# Is there a way to create a search screen in Lightswitch based on a dropdown

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I want to put a dropdown where the search box is on the search screen and have each entry associated with a different query. This is for a database used in my business and we currently have too many screens such as:

- All Equipment
- New Equipment
- Available Equipment
- Sold Equipment
- Unpaid Equipment
- Unpaid Commissions

I am using Lightswitch V2 from the 2012 RC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First click Add Data Item and add a Local Property of type String. For the sake of disscussion call it `SearchType`. In the Properties window of `SearchType` click Choice List. Populate the choice list with the values you listed above (i.e. All Equipment, New Equipment, etc.). Drag this onto the control tree and it will become an AutoCompleteBox.

Right click what I'm going to call your `Equipment` table and click Add Query. Give that a name like `EquipmentSearch`. Set up the query similar to what is seen in Step 2 of Yann's link:

[image]

Add a parameter but do not add a filter. Instead of `TownId` let's call it `SearchParam` and make it of type String.

Back in the Screen Designer, use Add Data Item to add the `EquipmentSearch` query to your screen. Drag it onto the tree so that it becomes a Grid View.

Click `EquipmentSeach` in the left hand list so that it expands. Then click on `SearchParam` and in it's Properties window, click on the box below Parameter Binding and select `SearchType`.

Open up `EquipmentSearch` in Query Designer again. In the upper right hand corner of the Query Designer, click the arrow next to Write Code and select `EqupimentSearch_PreprocessQuery`.

Now add code similar to the following:

VB.NET

```
    Private Sub EquipmentSearch_PreprocessQuery(SearchParam As System.Nullable(Of String), ByRef query As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of LightSwitchApplication.Equipment))
        Select Case SearchParam
            Case "New Equipment"
                query = From es In query
                        Where es.EquipStatus = "New"
                        Select es
            Case "Available Equipment"
                query = From es In query
                        Where es.EquipStatus = "Available"
                        Select es
            Case "Sold Equipment"
                query = From es In query
                        Where es.EquipStatus = "Sold"
                        Select es
            Case "Unpaid Equipment"
                query = From es In query
                        Where es.EquipStatus = "Unpaid"
                        Select es
            Case "Unpaid Commission"
                query = From es In query
                        Where es.EquipCommission = "Unpaid"
                        Select es
        End Select
    End Sub
```

C#

```
private void EquipmentSearch_PreprocessQuery(System.Nullable[] SearchParam, void Of, void String) {
    ((System.Linq.IQueryable[])(query));
    Of;
    LightSwitchApplication.Equipment;

    switch (SearchParam) {
        case "New Equipment":
            query = From es In query
                    Where es.EquipStatus = "New"
                    Select es
            break;
        case "Available Equipment":
            query = From es In query
                    Where es.EquipStatus = "Available"
                    Select es
            break;
        case "Sold Equipment":
            query = From es In query
                    Where es.EquipStatus = "Sold"
                    Select es
            break;
        case "Unpaid Equipment":
            query = From es In query
                    Where es.EquipStatus = "Unpaid"
                    Select es
            break;
        case "Unpaid Commission":
            query = From es In query
                    Where es.EquipCommission = "Unpaid"
                    Select es
            break;
    }
```

Let "All Equipment" and all others just fall through. If it falls through, then the Grid View will display a complete, unfiltered view of the entire table which is what I assume you want in the case of "All Equipment". In the other cases, use LINQ to customize the returned results as you like.

Comment: Bonus points for being able to use LINQ. I will try this right now, thanks for the detailed response!!!

Comment: This all works great for except one oddity. I get an "unable to load data. please check your network..." error when using: query = from es in query    where (DateTime.Now - es.DatePurchased).Days < 32   select es in the switch statement

Comment: There's a lot of things that cause that. Do other queries work and just this one gives the error? This is at runtime correct? Is this a Desktop app or a Web app? Are you using the Intrinsic database, SQL Server, or a WCF/RIA service? There is also this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitchgeneral/thread/9f6e3930-a953-4392-93e4-2fb3b3d952e9/ Though I'm not sure it's relevant. However, just to rule it out, set 'DateTime.Now` equal to a local variable and do the calculation on that.

Comment: All my other queries are fine. I tried creating a calculated field on the table as a bool and then making a simple "where es isNew" statement and still have the same issue. It is a 2 tier desktop ap and since I am debuging in VS I thought the database was SQLExpress. I am publishing to SQL Server 2008 on another machine but have not tried publishing with this error. I had added the field for date purchased to the table for this and wondered if the issue is related to the data change. I have changed allt he 1-1-1900 dates to valid dates in my test data.

Comment: I am going to work a theory that the issue is related to the fact that I added a Required column (Purchase Date) to the table and according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2010/11/30/anatomy-of-a-lightswitch-application-part-4-data-access-and-storage-2.aspx under schema versioning doing so is a non-deployable breaking change in the schema. I will try making the value optional and see if that helps.

Comment: The problem will be that you can't use DateTime.Now in a LINQ query in a PreProcessQuery method. Stote the value in a variable outside of the query, then use the variable in its place & you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can put multiple datagrids on the same screen, by adding screen query properties to the screen, then dragging them from the left-hand side of the designer onto the screen control tree.

Is that what you're asking?

Edit:

"*have each entry associated with a different query*" lead me to believe that you wanted multiple entities on one screen.

Does this help? [Creating a ComboBox filtered Search Screen](http://dotnettim.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/lightswitch-creating-a-combobox-filtered-search-screen/)

Comment: What I am trying to do is to have a drop down at the top of the screen with preset entries, each associated with a different query so I don't have to have so many screens just to display different sets of results of the same data.

Comment: For anyone who comes along with the same problem. In addition to Kyle's excellent suggestion, there are two links that might help as well. LightSwitch – http://dotnettim.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/lightswitch-creating-a-combobox-filtered-search-screen/ & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh499661.aspx I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

What you can also do in Lightswitch is to have an extra property defined in the screen that is assigned to the query, that is decided by the property displayed on the screen.

In the Query editor, assign the property to the field in the table, just like you would normally.

Now with the other property used for the display, select the Property_Changed event, and use the switch case used (like in embedded.kyle's example) to assign the property used in the query based on their selection. You can then assign the default value in the creation event for the screen.

This keeps code outside of the pre-process query and in the screen's code. It may a preference thing, but I like to only use preprocess query when I need to, such as cross-referencing tables that are not bound by a separate table to handle it.