# lightswitch query with parameter

Tags: c#, silverlight, parameters, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a list where I select an item. Based on some field of this item i want to filter a choice list in another Control.

Somehing like that:

`Select * from choiceItems Where choiceItem.ID = (Select ID from anotherTable where anotherTable.ID = selectedItem.ID)`

the problem is that it is possible that there are more ID returns. Maybe I want all the choiceItems with the ID = {3,2,1} etc.

I cant preprocess the query on the server since my parameter is depending on the selected item in the list. If i try to filter the result in the query editor i can only specify on parameter which can be only a single value (f.e. ID=2).

How do i do that in silverlight?

Also, another unrelated small problem: Is it possible to show the waiting cursor while loading a custom control in lightswitch (right now it just displays a grey area until the data and controls are loaded).

Answer (score 0):

> Select * from choiceItems Where choiceItem.ID = (Select ID from
>   anotherTable where anotherTable.ID = selectedItem.ID)

This is a many to many secenario, you need to make a WCF RIA Service with query parameter, a lot of work just for filtering.  The alternative is to make those tables related.

Comment: I am not sure if i will be able to change the database design. Could you please explain how it will work/how to make the tables related?

Comment: that's not a many to many scenario if there's only one row with that id.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to preprocess the query even if the parameter for the query is selected from a list. You can then use LINQ to return a subset of your `choiceItems` or, based on the selected parameter, skip the LINQ which would return all of the `choiceItems`.

I give a detailed example of doing this in my answer to the SO question:

[Is there a way to create a search screen in Lightswitch based on a dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485962/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-search-screen-in-lightswitch-based-on-a-dropdown/11509644#11509644)

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the exact syntax, but should be something like this:

first get the ID using LINQ

```
var FilterOnThisId=this.Query1.Where(x=>x.ID==selectedItem.ID).FirstOrDefault();
```

then query the colleciton you want

```
var filtedItems=this.Query2.Where(x=>x.ID==FilterOnThisId);
```