# override column sort light switch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a [Updates] table with [Version] column which is stored as a varchar in the sql server, and as a string in my entities.

How can I override the default comparer for that specific column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to add an `Order By` operator to the query you're using to create the table in the `_PreprocessQuery` method.

I go over the details on how to write a `_PreprocessQuery` method in this SO question: [Is there a way to create a search screen in Lightswitch based on a dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485962/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-search-screen-in-lightswitch-based-on-a-dropdown/11509644#11509644)

Then check out the ordering operator samples from MSDN to sort your column however you want:

[C# Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SQL-Ordering-Operators-050af19e)

[VB.NET Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb737912)